# How to check for collision in if-statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have method to buy a tile and i need to check if it collides with another tile owned by player.

I know about func OnCollisionEnter and etc but i think i need other way and check it in if-statement.

```
void BuyTile()
{
    if (_selected.tag == "Free") // if no owners
    {
        _selected.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        _selected.tag = "Player1";
        pc.CountTiles();
    }
    _selected = null;
}
```

i need smth like that if `(_selected.tag == "Free" && _selected.CollideWithGO.tag == "Player1")` but idk how to do that using no func

Comment: Why do you think you OnCollisionEnter won't work for you in this case?

Comment: Also the `Physics` class can check for things like this.

Comment: solve it. used Physics.OverlapSphere

Comment: please don't add a solution to your question. Instead rather add it as answer to your own question in order to show others there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p.s: solve it

```
bool Neighboor(GameObject centerTarget)
{
    bool GotTrue = false;
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(centerTarget.transform.position, 1f);
    for (int i = 0; i<hitColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        if(hitColliders[i].tag == "Player1")
        {
            GotTrue = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (GotTrue)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the collision:

```
public class CollisionTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    Collision collision;

    void Update()
    {
        if (collision != null && collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Colliding with Player!");
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        this.collision = collision;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        this.collision = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use OnCollisionStay (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) which does exactly the same

Comment: @StevenDelrue that would not work as it's only called when you're touching. You still need to nullify the reference on collision exit. You could do it in update but why bother with repeatedly setting and unsetting the reference when you can do it once for enter, and once for exit.